# How can I create thumbnails on my page using jquery colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want thumbnails on my page. I want them to be enlarged while we click on them. is there any way to do it by using jquery colorbox?

Comment: You should really consider using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

On left side panel add image as hyper link as below ,

```js
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1'});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
<div align="left">
<ol>
       <a class='gallery' href="image1.gif"><img src="image1.gif" width=90 height=90></a>
       <a class='gallery' href="image2.gif"><img src="image2.gif" width=90 height=90></a>
       <a class='gallery' href="image3.gif"><img src="image3.gif" width=90 height=90></a>
<ol>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```